# Promise.all() is slower than using await for each promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I'm doing some testing for performance and was looking at Promise.all() in node/js. However, after testing this it's actually slower than using await for the 3 promises I want to resolve. I'm simply returning some data back from a mongodb database.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this just due to the way the event loop is working?

**Promise.all() : 234.820ms**

```
  // Init db connection
  const db = client.db('docker-client1');
  const productsCollection = db.collection('ICProductData');
  const rulesCollection = db.collection('SPRuleData');
  const customersCollection = db.collection('ARCustomerData');
  // Main function

  const CustomerCode = 'FINE';
  const ProductCode = 'BEDCABINET';

  let customers = customersCollection
    .find({ _id: CustomerCode })
    .project({ PriceCode: 1, BillToAccountCode: 1 })
    .toArray();

  let products = productsCollection
    .find({ _id: ProductCode })
    .project({ 'Price.PriceCode': 1, 'Price.SellingPrice': 1 })
    .toArray();

  let rules = rulesCollection
    .find({
      $and: [
        {
          $or: [
            {
              $and: [
                { What1Code: ProductCode, What1Type: 'Product' },
                { Who1Code: CustomerCode, Who1Type: 'Customer' }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    })
    .toArray();

  const results = await Promise.all([customers, products, rules]);
  console.timeEnd();
```

**Simply using await : 127.239ms**

```
  // Init db connection
  const db = client.db('docker-client1');
  const productsCollection = db.collection('ICProductData');
  const rulesCollection = db.collection('SPRuleData');
  const customersCollection = db.collection('ARCustomerData');
  // Main function

  const CustomerCode = 'FINE';
  const ProductCode = 'BEDCABINET';

  const custReq = await customersCollection
    .find({ _id: CustomerCode })
    .project({ PriceCode: 1, BillToAccountCode: 1 })
    .toArray();
  const prodReq = await productsCollection
    .find({ _id: ProductCode })
    .project({ 'Price.PriceCode': 1, 'Price.SellingPrice': 1 })
    .toArray();

  let rulesReq = await rulesCollection
    .find({
      $and: [
        {
          $or: [
            {
              $and: [
                { What1Code: ProductCode, What1Type: 'Product' },
                { Who1Code: CustomerCode, Who1Type: 'Customer' }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    })
    .toArray();

  console.timeEnd();
```

Comment: How many samples of each did you run?

Comment: I ran each about 10 times and on average the Promise.all() is always around 250ms with the standard awaits coming in around 100-120ms

Comment: I would rather put the culprit on your db not able to manage the three simultaneous calls correctly. What if you do `const custReq = customersCollection.find.... prodReq = productsCol...` and then `await custReq; await prodReq; await rulesReq;`? That is, also make 3 concurrent calls and wait for them.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido - doing that brings it up to the same sort of time using Promise.all() around the 240ms mark

Comment: So the answer to your question is "not in any significant way".

Comment: There's no console.time, only timeEnd. If you believe you measured it correctly, this is specific to how your DB handles simultaneous queries, not to Node or promises.

Comment: Hi @estus it looks like I emitted console.time() from the original snippets by accident. I can confirm it's there in the code that was run.

Comment: I am curious to know if you put your `console.time()` where it says 'main function' or somewhere else. If you put it at 'main function', maybe try opening 3 separate database connections (one for each promise) and then running both versions again, to see how much difference that makes.

Comment: Not that it makes a difference two years later, but I believe that the mongodb native driver doesn't actually start the request until the microtask queue is processed. Not sure, but that might be why its serial, well, because it is. Some kind of connection/session pooling would fix this idk. Getting the same prob rn. Though aggregations solve all.

Comment: @Adam91Holt Did you ever figure out what was the issue. i faced the same issue the only difference is that I was not making any database call. i was just using axios to make endpoint calls and still promise.all is slower.

Answer (score -2):

The method toArray() does not return a Promise in Old versions of Mongo. This could be the explanation about timings. You could put a console.log with timing after each toArray() they should run in the same millisecond (same tick). If this is not the case, it could be an indication that toArray() is waiting for the response... so you are running sequentially. You could try to resolve this with: let myProm = collection.find(filter).exec()

Comment: `toArray()` did (and still does) return a thenable that executes the query when used in `Promise.all` or being `await`ed.

Comment: No it doesn't, you were reading the wrong docs. OP is using the nodejs driver, [`toArray` returns *a promise for* an array](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.10/classes/FindCursor.html#toArray).

Comment: @Bergi you are right.